# PHP set a maximum image count to show

Tags: php

I have a code that pulls images from a folder and displays those on the website. The Problem is I only want to show a maximum of 12 images (random). As I am not familiar with PHP I hope somebody can help here.

The code I have is:

```
<?php
    foreach($this->images as $image)
    {
        $path = ($image->remote == 1) ? $image->path : $this->ipbaseurl.$this->settings->imgpath;
        echo '<img src="'.$path.$image->fname.$image->type.'" alt="'.$this->p->street_address.'" width="320" style="margin: 10px 5px 0px 5px;"/> ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Images are refult of all or random?

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help - what a great community - that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($this->images as $count => $image) {
    if ($count >= 12) { break; }
```

or even earlier, depending on how you're setting $this->images you might be able to reduce that to an array of just 12 entries

Comment: Please note, that this will not print the images in a random order.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $count= 0;
    foreach($this->images as $image)
    {
        if($count > 12)
                break;

        $path = ($image->remote == 1) ? $image->path : $this->ipbaseurl.$this->settings->imgpath;
        echo '<img src="'.$path.$image->fname.$image->type.'" alt="'.$this->p->street_address.'" width="320" style="margin: 10px 5px 0px 5px;"/> ';
        $count++;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thier are many ways to do this , you have to put limit on foreach loop , one way to achieve it is below.
here in below code i put `$i=0;` so count start from zero then inside foreach loop i put increment on i  and put limit and break the code if if condition success  `if (++$i == 11) break;`

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
  foreach($this->images as $image)
  {
   if (++$i == 11) break;
   $path = ($image->remote == 1) ? $image->path : $this->ipbaseurl.$this->settings->imgpath;
    echo '<img src="'.$path.$image->fname.$image->type.'" alt="'.$this->p->street_address.'" width="320" style="margin: 10px 5px 0px 5px;"/> ';

   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display 12 random images out of the images array, you could try something like this:

```
if(count($this->images) > 12) {
    $randomKeys = array_rand($this->images, 12);
} else {
    $randomKeys = array_rand($this->images, count($this->images));
}
foreach($randomKeys as $key) {
    $image = $this->images[$key];
    $path = ($image->remote == 1) ? $image->path : $this->ipbaseurl.$this->settings->imgpath;
    echo '<img src="'.$path.$image->fname.$image->type.'" alt="'.$this->p->street_address.'" width="320" style="margin: 10px 5px 0px 5px;"/> ';
}
```

Select 12 random keys from the array and then just loop through the keys. If less than 12 items are in the image array, use all items of the array but in a random order.